# Combining the use of update and append for dictionaries

Tags: python

Suppose that I have a data file in which a string (say 'a,'b','c'...) appear multiple times. I wish to use 'a' and 'b' as keys, and they have multiple values associated with them.

If my dictionary is dict, and I use `dict1.update({'a':1})` followed by `dict1.update[{'a':2}]`, the 2 overwrites value 1. However, I cannot use `dict['a'].append([2])`, unless the key 'a' is already in the file.

Consequently, I'm looking for some way to check if a key is already in my list, in which case I use append, or if it isn't, to use update. What is a simple conditional statement that would work in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)
2. Use your own implementation of defaultdict

Assuming that your file looks like this:

```
a 1
b 4
a 2
...
```

Then you can do this:

```
import collections 
answer = collections.defaultdict(list) 
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        key, value = line.strip().split()
        answer[key].append(value)
```

If you don't want to use defaultdict, then:

```
answer = {}
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        key, value = line.strip().split()
        if key not in answer:
            answer[key] = []
        answer[key].append(value)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['a'].append(1)
d['a'].append(2)
```

Basically you initialize it with a factory function that will return what the 'default' value should be, and when you try and get an item from the dictionary by key it will run that function if the key does not yet exist. In this case it will return an empty list.

Comment: What is the input "list" in this case?

Comment: `list` is the builtin function `list()`, which if you try running at the interpreter you will see that it returns an empty list. Note that you should leave off the parenthesis because you do not want to invoke the function when you are creating the defaultdict, instead you want to give that object a reference to the function so that it can call it each time it needs to create a default value. `list` could be replaced with any function that returns the default value you want for the dictionary (whether it is builtin or defined yourself as long as it doesn't take any arguments).

Answer (score 0):

To check if a dict has a key, you can do `dict.has_key('a')`

Comment: `has_key()` is deprecated far a long time now.  Use `key in my_dict` instead, or in this particular case `dict.setdefault()` or `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = dict.fromkeys(st,[]) # where st is your string.
dict1['a'].append(1)
dict1['a'].append(2)
```

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(x, [])` doesn't work the way you expect.  It will create a dictionary with all keys associated with the same list object.  Add something to this list object will add it everywhere: http://ideone.com/tlwHvR

Comment: Oh. did not know that. So is there any remedy of this, other than defaultDict ?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, including the dictionary comprehension `{k: [] for k in keys}`.

Comment: No I meant using fromkeys. Basically someone here told me about this and I think this is pretty sleek. Though defaultDict seems to be much sleeker. :)

Comment: The second parameter of `dict.fromkeys()` can only reasonably be immutable value, so there is no sane way to use `dict.fromkeys()` in this particular case.